# iOS random problem of navigation, buttons not reacting for tap each time

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, rx-swift, back

I have noticed a problem with the navigation in our app.

Back buttons on UINavigationController for dismiss a viewController, or ok button for dismiss keyboard not reacting on tap each time. I have to press several times to finally enter in the button action method.
But i can see the button hilighting on each tap.

- My viewControllers are pushed/presented and dismiss from the main thread.
- My viewControllers is pushed/presented once.
- There is no hidden view who catch the tap.
- In the memory graph, I have no viewController instance leacked.
- In the instrument I Have no CPU hight usage, No network call in progress.

App is in swift and uses rxSwift.
We don't use segue, all screens are pushed programmatically.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem ?
Have you something for me to check, explore or some advices ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my problem. It was caused by an override of isEnable method in a UIButton extension for my buttons.
I had changed the isUserInterrationEnable accordingly to isEnable.
Back button in navigation controller and ok button in keyboard InputAccessoryView are also UIButtons.
So my extension makes conflict with the system behavior and makes systems buttons not working all times.
removing isUserInterractionEnable in the isEnable override solve this problem.